# Exclude blank columns from XML

Tags: sql, xml, postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I am trying to get Table Rows to XMLs. I am able to do it in the following way and the only issue I have is that it also generates XML tags for blank columns.

```
create table test_niks_01(x int, y varchar(10));

insert into test_niks_01 values(1, 'ABC');
INSERT INTO test_niks_01 values(2);
INSERT INTO test_niks_01 values(3, '');

--SelecT query_to_xml('SELECT * FROM test_niks_01', false, false, '');

select xmlelement(name "Root", xmlforest (x as X, y as Y));
```

Output XML:

```
<Root><x>1</x><y>ABC</y></Root>
<Root><x>2</x></Root>
<Root><x>3</x><y></y></Root>
```

Expected XML:

```
<Root><x>1</x><y>ABC</y></Root>
<Root><x>2</x></Root>
<Root><x>3</x></Root>
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use `nullif()` to turn empty strings to `null`s in the second column:

```
select xmlelement(name "Root", xmlforest (x as X, nullif(y, '') as Y)) from test_niks_01
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=1eb350095bed2758464f5e2740cc9a75)**:

```
| xmlelement                      |
| :------------------------------ |
| <Root><x>1</x><y>ABC</y></Root> |
| <Root><x>2</x></Root>           |
| <Root><x>3</x></Root>           |
```

Comment: Hey, do u know to check with numeric columns? Sorry I know it is not part of the original question...